# Examples of good UI for selecting multiple records

Tags: database, user-interface, language-agnostic

I'm currently revisiting an area of my Windows-based software and looking at changing the relationship from 1->M to M->M. As a result, I need to adjust the UI to accommodate selecting multiple related records.

There are a lot of ways to handle this that are common, but usually pretty clunky. Examples include the two-pane list of all items, and list of selected items, or a list of all records and a checkbox beside each one that applies.

In my case, there may be an awful lot (in the tens of thousands) of records that could be associated, so I'll probably need to include some kind of search mechanism.

**I'm not looking for a hard and fast answer** -- I can implement something pretty easily that's functional, I'm looking to see if anyone here has come up with (or seen) any great UIs for doing this kind of thing, whether it's web based, Windows, Mac, Unix, whatever.

Images or links to them would be appreciated!

Edit: here's an example of what I'm considering:

[image: Sample Search UI 1]

Comment: Do you want to provide the facility to edit what is returned? (Just checking; seems unlikely, but would affect the design).

Comment: No, it's merely a selection method. In my example above, the link could take you to that person's record to edit it there if required, or pop up a list of options, including "remove", "edit" and so on.

Comment: What's the average/maximum number of associated people for one? It's important for the UI design process.

Comment: Not an average, but the most common number of associated records would be 1 or 2, but it wouldn't be uncommon to have 30 or 40.

Comment: If possible, see my answer. regards

Comment: COMIC SANS!!! NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!!!!

Comment: That's just the font used by Balsamiq Mockup. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like the way StackOverflow relates many tags with many questions:

[image]

<sub>*Items are displayed as user types*</sub>

1. You start obviously with the record you want to associate multiple items with.
2. As you type the search displays the matches ( no need to press on "Search" )
3. The user select the desired record ( Sorting would be nice. SO uses "tag relevance".  For instance typing 'a' brings Java rather than asp because Java has more questions than asp,  in your case relevance may be the user name )
4. The system creates the relationship ( in memory )
5. If a number of records (  5+  ) are filling the input field, they are moved into a semi-regid area ( not a SO problem because it only has 5 tag withing a single question, but in your case something like the "interesting tags" feature would be needed )

[image]

<sub>*Associated items are moved to a "rigid" area*</sub>

Of course in an ordered manner ( using a table )

- Finally when the user end with the association it clicks SAVE or CANCEL buttons.

This approach has more efficiency by not needing to have the user press on "search" or "add other"  which distracts them from what they're doing, it is being said it interrupts its train of thought.

Also, if you make the user grab the mouse to click on something while they are typing the UI is less efficient ( I think there is something called the [Hick's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hick%27s_law) about that, but quite frankly I may be wrong )

As you see this approach is pretty much already what you have in mind, but adding some facilities to make the user happier ( The danger would be if the user loves this approach and wants it in other parts of the system )

Comment: Great example, I never even thought of that!

Comment: @Tim Sullivan: heheh and it's in front of us every day isn't it? That's a characteristic of a good UI, you don't think about it. Otherwise you always have that bad feeling about that damn interface that makes you waste your time .....

Comment: Thank you!! I hope you have great success with the implementation, post an screen shot when you're done would you?

Comment: But still, you have to click "add", so you must move your hand to the mouse. Or is it just me, that hitting enter doesn't work here? (Safari 4 for Windows). Another thing (more important I think) is, that this solution works only for data that can be presented in a compact way, and is not complex (like tag - just a single word). If you deal with more complicated data, with more attributes or complex relationships with other entities, providing a neat browser, that allows you to search data in a variety of ways in a modal dialog is much more clear solution. Still - work's here.

Comment: And as Oscar requested - it would be great if you share the final results with us:)

Comment: @Darius: This isn't necessarily for a web application. This could be a Windows or Mac application, or an iPhone application, or a web application. How it works is SO is simply related to the fact it's a web app, but the general concepts could be applied elsewhere. And I will share what I end up doing when it's done, but it might be some time away. :-)

Answer (score 3):

It's an interesting and fairly common UI problem, how to efficiently select items.  I'm assuming that you are intending on having the user first select a single item and that the mechanism you are interested is how to choose other items that get related to this first single item.

There ares various select methods.  From a usability standpoint, it would be preferable to just have ONE method used for each scenario.  Then when the user sees it, they will know what to do.

various selection techniques:

1. dropdown list - obvious for single selects.
2. open list multi select - eg: a multiline textbox that shows 10 or 20 lines and has a scroll bar
3. dropdown list where you select then hit and 'add' link or button to add multiple selects
4. list moving - where you have two open lists, with all the choices available in the left list, you select a few then click a button to move your selection to the right list.
5. Check boxes - good for just a few choices of multiple selection possibilities.
6. List of items, each with an 'add' button next to them - good for short lists

You've said that you'll have thousands of possible choices, so that eliminates 1 and 5.  Really, thousands will eliminate all of them, as the usability doesn't scale well with more than a few hundred in the list.

If you can count on the user to filter the list, like in your example, then 6 may be suitable.  If you think of how Facebook picture tagging works, I think that it fairly efficient for long lists:  background: Facebook picture tagging is a mechanism that allows you to assign one or more people to portions of an image - ie 'tag' them.

When you select an image to tag (ie the 'single item') and wish to relate other items(people) to it, A dialog box pops up.  It contains the top 6 or so names that you've used in the past, and a textbox where you can start to type the person's name you wish to use.  As you type, the list dynamically changes to reduce the number of people to only those who contain the letter sequence you've typed.  This works very well for large lists, but it does rely on the user typing to filter.  It also will rely on use of scripting to intelligently reduce the list based on the user's input.

For your application it would rely on the user performing this step once for each association, as I'm assuming that the other items won't all have similar names!

Here's an image of the Facebook tagging application: http://screencast.com/t/9MPlpJQJzBQ

Comment: I quite like the Facebook tagging method. Having "recent" or possibly "most common options based on context" is really great.

Answer (score 2):

A search feature that filters records in real time as you type would probably be a good idea to include. Another would be the possibility to sort the records.

Since there may be a lot of records, the best choice in this case is probably to have a separate area which displays what you have already chosen, so that the user won't have to scroll around the selection areas to find what they already have.

Answer (score 2):

[self-explanatory GUI http://img25.imageshack.us/img25/8568/28666917.png](http://img25.imageshack.us/img25/8568/28666917.png)

Link to the [original image](http://img25.imageshack.us/img25/8568/28666917.png)

Another thing is, that in my opinion your problem is not about selecting multiple records, but filtering those tens of thousands of records. M->M association can be implemented in variety of way, but the tricky part is to provide a convenient and logical way to browse/search the huge amount of data.

Comment: Search field in the modal dialog filters the records instantly as you type - in iTunes style.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest not having to click *add more* to be able to search. The warning at the right is nice, but IMHO it should only say the search displays results as the user types.

Sorting a column (maybe along with the search) would also be a nice functionality. I'd suggesting it being done by clicking on the header of the table, with some icon indicating whether the sort is ascending or descending.

I'd suggest also the search to do an [approximate string matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) in case there are no or few results. It is so annoying not being able to find something you don't remember exactly.

Finally, for testing the first impression (though not the functionality itself), I'd suggest uploading it to the [5 second test](http://fivesecondtest.com/) and see what you get.

Comment: The "warning" is just a sticky note to let you guys know what I'm talking about, it's not part of the UI. :-) Also, what I'm looking for isn't a critique of what I posted, but rather examples of existing apps or suggested mockups of alternate UIs.

Comment: added one more suggestion for first impression retrieval

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you have mocked up is a pretty good way to do it.  When you think about the tags-to-posts relationship on a blog (or on SO even), that is many-to-many and it is usually implemented very similarly:  for one post, you search for (or, since they are simple strings, directly enter) as many tags as you want to associate with it.  I can't really think of any many-to-many relationships I encounter often, although I know there are probably many...

Comment: There are tons of examples. A meeting could have many people, a person could have many meetings. This can be compounded if you have multiple resources attached to a record. For example, a meeting might have many people and many pieces of equipment. This isn't a stated requirement for my original question, but it is something I have to deal with in many cases in the software I've been working on.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of important questions to consider - how many records will typically be used (as opposed to available for association)? Will there be a large number of records on one side of the association (given the switch from 1->M, this seems likely)?

If one of the quantities of records is usually very small (<10, I'd say), call this the LHS (because it usually is), then the best way to associate may be to allow searches for LHS and RHS items, then drag-and-drop them onto a list - LHS items onto the list proper; RHS items into the existing LHS items. That way, it's intuitive to specify a relation between to items. You could also add other options like "associate with all", or a grouping pen so you can assign several records to several other records - nothing is tedious like having to do 15 drags-and-drops of the same record.

In fact, I think that's the most crucial bit of any M->M UI design - minimize repetition. Doing the same thing over for 100s of records (remember that if "nobody will ever...", they will) is unfun, especially if it's complex. I know this seems to contradict my earlier advice, but I don't think it does - design for the typical use case, but make sure that the atypical ones do not make the program unusable.

Comment: I'd add a mockup or reference an existing application if I was any good at mockups or if I could remember right now (it's 5 AM) any applications that use this. Sorry!